# Content not centered in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```css
.course-card{
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center course-card">
  <div class="col-md-6 course-progress">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 course-info">
    <div id="div2-1 course-name">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2-2 course-button">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ispb2.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug81L.png)

I am trying to center my content in bootstrap but even after adding `d-flex align-items-center` the content is still off and as you can see on the picture, it is not even in the middle but the lower part has more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `d-flex align-items-center` as a class doesn't do anything by itself. Since we can't see the rest of your CSS it is unclear what that code would be doing.

However, here's something you could try:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 150px;">
  <div style="flex-direction: row;">
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-direction: column">
      <div>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can use the dotted blue line around each div to help reference how the elements are positioned relative to each other.

Your divs are properly aligned, but the text within the `p` tags is not spaced correctly vertically. In my example, the `p` elements are all aligned vertically with `align-self: center`, which should fix the issue you were noticing.

Comment: There must be something with my code because I can see that it works perfectly here but for me it's still not in the middle vertically, must be something with my css

Comment: @Kyle It would probably help to see the rest of the css you have. row, d-flex, align-items-center, course-card, div2-2, course-button, etc are all classes that probably have their own css declarations which are throwing things off.